# Why is my state not mapped to my properties after change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Example from '../components/example.jsx';

class ExampleContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Example isUploading={this.props.isUploading}/>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isUploading: state.isUploading
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ExampleContainer);
```

My reducer :

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import * as actionTypes from '../constants/action-types.js';

const initialState = {
  isUploaded: false,
  isUploading: false
};


function isUploading(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.IS_UPLOADED:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function isUploaded(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.IS_UPLOADING:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default combineReducers({
  isUploading,
  isUploaded,
});
```

I see my isUploading state changing in my console but the property isUploading on my Example component is not changing. It has the same value as the property that was defined at the first time. I also see that the mapStateToProps function is only being called once.

Comment: add example.jsx code also

Comment: How/when are you dispatching the update?

Answer (score 1):

(Moved from comment for space and formatting.)

Where is your reducer mapped to? E.g., if your reducer is mapped like this:

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  uploading: uploadingReducer,
  // etc
})
```

then  your `mapStateToProps` would be (noting `state` destructuring):

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ uploading }) => ({
  isUploading: uploading.isUploading
});
```

It's likely it's changing as expected, but instead of passing a boolean, you're passing the entire state contained in the reducer.

Comment: but what if i have multiple states to map? (what is the cause but i removed them to make this question simpler)

Comment: @JimPeeters What if? You can map whatever you want, but you still have to be mapping the right things. Without knowing what your payload is it's still impossible to know if the code as-is makes sense. (Or how the property is being used in the sub-component, for that matter.) What does the state look like when you view it in [redux-devtools](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools)?